# Capture first digit after decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this line here:

```
\d(?!.*\d)
```

whereby it captures the last digit after a period.
i.e:
6.3059

Will return "9", HOWEVER, what I really want it to do - is return 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex matches any digit that is not followed by a digit, that is why you get `9` as output.

You can use a capturing group:

```
\d\.(\d)
```

The value will be in Group 1. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB3iL3/1).

JS code:

```js
var re = /\d\.(\d)/; 
var str = '6.3059';
var m;
 
if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = m[1];
}
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Comment: I found this and used it:
\d{0,2}\.(\d{1,1})?

But now that I see this, i feel really dumb.
Forgive me, and thank you!

Comment: The `\d{0,2}\.(\d{1,1})` can be written as `\d{0,2}\.(\d)` and it should work here, too. If the first digit is optional, just use `\.(\d)` or `(?<=\.)\d`.

Comment: I'm using this, and it's returning for a value of: 2.459 (if i alert it) 2.4,4 in the popup - am i doing something wrong do you think?

Comment: The only problem you have is that you did not tell me what language you are using :)

Comment: I'm trying to sub the two parts of a number back into a query string to build out a image from a css sprite. sorry to be a pain, I REALLY appreciate your help!

Comment: I have provided code for plain JS, I think you can figure out how to apply it to your specific case.